# Multi-tenant database. One collection or one db per tenant?

Tags: multi-tenant, document-oriented-db

For a multi-tenancy architecture for a web application using a document-oriented database I can see two conceivable options:

- Having one database per tenant, and the collections logically separate different kinds of object.
- Having one collection per tenant, and all user data is stored in one database, with some kind of flag or object type identifier on each record.

Have there been any studies or has any documentation been produced regarding these two options and the differences between them?

Is there a particular standard or good reason why someone designing a web application which allows multiple users to store vastly different kinds of data would choose one over the other?

Aside from speed/efficiency issues, are there any other things to be said about this that would influence the decision?

**EDIT** I'm aware some of the terminology might be database specific, so for all wondering I am specifically referring to MongoDB.

Comment: https://docs.mongohq.com/use-cases/multi-tenant.html

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't want tenant specific collections. In my application, I usually hard code collection names, in the same way as I'd hardcode table names if I were using SQL tables. There'd be one `comments` collection that stores all comments for a blog. I would not want to deal with collection names like `comments_tenant_1` and `comments_tenant_2`, because 1) that feels error prone, and 2) would make the application code more complicated (collection names would have to be replaced with functions that computed the collection name). And 3) the number of collections in a single database could grow huge, which would make a list of all collections look daunting, and also MongoDB isn't built for having very many collections (see the link in the comment below your question, which David B posted, https://docs.mongohq.com/use-cases/multi-tenant.html).

However, database names aren't coupled to application data structures, and you can grant permissions on databases (but not on single collections). So one database per tenant could be reasonable. As could be a per document `tenant_id` field in a single database for all tenants (see the above-mentioned link).